# SNI hostname error when using phonegap File Transfer over SSL/HTTPS on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, sni

I am attempting to use the FileTransfer plugin on phonegap which works fine on some Android devices however on others the request is being cancelled and the server is is logging an SNI error:

```
Hostname X provided via SNI, but no hostname provided in HTTP request
```

This is what the client is failing on. The stream is cancelled:

```
    D/FileTransfer(15642): java.io.IOException: stream was reset: CANCEL
D/FileTransfer(15642):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy.SpdyStream$SpdyDataOutputStream.waitUntilWritable(SpdyStream.java:664)
D/FileTransfer(15642):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy.SpdyStream$SpdyDataOutputStream.writeFrame(SpdyStream.java:640)
D/FileTransfer(15642):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy.SpdyStream$SpdyDataOutputStream.write(SpdyStream.java:601)
D/FileTransfer(15642):  at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:417)
D/FileTransfer(15642):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
D/FileTransfer(15642):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
D/FileTransfer(15642):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

I have tried everything, including manually specifying the corrent host as a Host header and I have seen no results.

Is there something I am missing?

Again, the exact same JS and server-side code runs fine on other Android devices and iOS devices.

Comment: SNI on Android is only supported via HttpsURLConnection on devices with Android 2.3 and higher. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs